# Using .map to load API data into Slick-Slider Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, slick.js

Currently I'm using `react-slick slider` to have a carousel component in my website and **Strapi** as my CMS. I want to fill in this content through my CMS API that I am fetching. Normally I use this piece of code to fill in my content:

```
export default function Page({posts}) {
  return (
    {posts &&
            posts.map((team) => (
               {posts.Title}
      ))}
```

But here for my `<Slider>` I am using this piece of code and can't add my `.map` function since the class is extending component:

```
export default class BlogPost extends Component {
  render() {
    var settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
      initialSlide: 0,
      nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow />,
      prevArrow: <SamplePrevArrow />,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            infinite: true,
            dots: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    };

    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <Slider {...settings}>
            <div>
              <img style={{ width: "90%" }} src="/countries1.png" />
              <div
                style={{
                  minHeight: "100px",
                  padding: "30px",
                  textAlign: "center",
                }}
              >
                <div>
                  Reasons to Acquire Antigua & Barbuda Citizenship by Investment{" "}
                </div>
                <br />

                <div>Read More</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h3>2</h3>
            </div>
          </Slider>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/blogs");
  const posts = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { posts },
  };
}
```

Is there any way I can use the `.map` function here for the image and title in my `<Slider>` component?

Ive added a sandbox of my code, codesandbox.io/s/recursing-solomon-c20on?file=/src/Slide.tsx just here I've put in dummy data in posts array but in actual it is coming from getStaticProps API call

Comment: If I understood your requirement correctly.
 You could call the `getStaticProps` in `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate`, store the result in the state using `setState` and then use the values to map the `divs` and `img` in the `render`?

Comment: Could you please show this in code form since I'm still new to React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will be of use as-is. But this is the general idea.

```js
const sliderSettings = {
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  initialSlide: 0,
  nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow />,
  prevArrow: <SamplePrevArrow />,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true,
      },
    },
  ],
};
export default class BlogPost extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {posts: []};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    getStaticProps().then(data => {
      this.setState({
        posts: data.props.posts
      });
    });
  }
  getSlides() {
    return this.state.posts.map((post) => {
      // ... generate divs and imgs here.
    })
  }
  render() {
    const slides = this.getSlides()

    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <Slider {...sliderSettings}>
            {slides}
          </Slider>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/blogs");
  const posts = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { posts },
  };
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting Cannot read property 'posts' of null. Ive added a sandbox of my code, https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-solomon-c20on?file=/src/Slide.tsx just here I've put in dummy data in posts array but in actual it is coming from getStaticProps API call

Comment: I haven't defined the state. https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-sound-1yo3b?file=/src/Slide.jsx I've updated the snippet in the answer.

Comment: This gave me ReferenceError: getStaticProps is not defined

Comment: Is `getStaticProps` function available in the in the file? Either via import or defined in the file itself?

Comment: Yea, but I'm trying a new carousel component for this now which had a few issues if you could check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69002765/loading-data-in-react-multi-carousel-using-map-function-gives-length-of-undef