# Loading data in react-multi-carousel using .map function gives 'length' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, carousel

Currently I'm using react-multi-carousel for my carousel component and I'm trying to replicate the 1st half of this Sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/2omn67p8kj with my API data. I am using .map in my Simple.js file to map out my data from the API but I get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined Currently this is my Sandbox and code:

In my actual project I am using getStaticProps() to fetch my API, but here I have included an array for reference.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-firefly-446yf?file=/src/App.tsx

Code:

```
const responsive = {
  desktop: {
    breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1024 },
    items: 3,
    paritialVisibilityGutter: 60
  },
  tablet: {
    breakpoint: { max: 1024, min: 464 },
    items: 2,
    paritialVisibilityGutter: 50
  },
  mobile: {
    breakpoint: { max: 464, min: 0 },
    items: 1,
    paritialVisibilityGutter: 30
  }
};

const Simple = ({ deviceType, posts }) => {
  return (
    <Carousel
      ssr
      partialVisbile
      deviceType={deviceType}
      itemClass="image-item"
      responsive={responsive}
    >
      {posts && posts.map((image) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <Image
              draggable={false}
              style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
              src={image.Thumbnail}
            />
            <h1>{image.Title}</h1>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </Carousel>
  );
};

export default Simple;

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/blogs");
  const posts = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { posts },
  };
}
```

Comment: You have a declared variable of `post` in your file and then you are trying to read `posts` from prop which you never passed. Just drop the `post` in the prop, the code will work.

Comment: Could you please show the example in the Sandbox since I'm still new to React

Comment: I see you have already fixed your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line [here](https://github.com/YIZHUANG/react-multi-carousel/blob/18479e77f21fffde5affe1ac4b18e05f3a5dcd9d/src/Carousel.tsx#L329) is probably throwing the error.

In the code `Simple.tsx`, we might want to send a react child instead of `undefined` if `posts` are not available. Something like this.

```
{posts ? posts.map((image) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Image
          draggable={false}
          style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
          src={image.img}
        />
        <h1>{image.Title}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }) : <div />}
```